# Update raw json file open in Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a JSON file which is frequently updated. I would like to view this file in a web browser and see the changes made to it in real-time, without having to manually refresh the page. I understand that displaying the JSON data on a HTML page and using AJAX or Websockets could be a solution, but I would prefer to view the raw JSON file directly if possible. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Couldn't find any solution.

Comment: You can't with HTTP alone. It's a request/response protocol. No request = no response.

Comment: On second thought it _may_ be possible using `multipart/x-mixed-replace`. It's an old technology, I don't know if it works with JSON and would need a server to implement this, so your mileage may vary and unless you can get more evidence this will work, you may have to implement/test this. Some googling suggests it doesn't work in Chrome, so it might be firefox only.